# how to determine the rank of the calling process in a bash script?

Tags: mpi, slurm

I am developing a bash script to compress a huge number of files using MPI to assign set of files for each processor on the supercomputer.

This is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Source directory containing subfolders
SOURCE_DIR="../data"

# Destination directory to store compressed files
DEST_DIR="../zipFiles"

# Create the destination directory if it doesn't exist
mkdir -p "$DEST_DIR"

# Count the number of subfolders
SUBFOLDER_COUNT=$(find "$SOURCE_DIR" -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -path "$SOURCE_DIR" | wc -l)

# Print the number of subdirectories:
echo "The number of subdirectories is $SUBFOLDER_COUNT"

# Set the number of subfolders to compress in each batch
echo "The maximum number of subdirectories per batch is $DirPerBatch"

# COMPRESSED FILE NUMBER
k=1

cd "$SOURCE_DIR"

rank=$OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK

# Calculate the start and end index of files for this rank
start=$((rank * DirPerBatch))
end=$((start + DirPerBatch - 1))
echo "DBG:      rank:$rank"
echo "DBG:      sta: $start"
echo "DBG:      end: $end"
# Initialize the 'files' variable
files=""

# Loop to gather files for this rank
for ((i = start; i <= end && i < SUBFOLDER_COUNT; i++)); do
    subfolder_index=$i
    subfolder_name=$(printf "%05d" "$subfolder_index")

    # Check if the subfolder exists before adding it
    if [ -d "$subfolder_name" ]; then
        files+="$subfolder_name "  # Use += to append to 'files'
    fi
done

# Create the compressed file for this rank
tar czf $DEST_DIR/$((rank + 1)).tar.gz $files
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Rank $rank: Successfully compressed $rank.tar.gz"
else
    echo "Rank $rank: Failed to compress $rank.tar.gz"
fi
```

NOTE 1: the variable `DirPerBatch` is declared and exported in the job bash script that is submitted to the supercomputer.

NOTE 2: The job script loads `intel/2019 module` which uses the following command to execute the mpi program: `mpiexec.hydra`

THE PROBLEM: this line `rank=$OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK` does not get the rank of the process correctly, in fact it the variable `OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK` returns nothing to be stored in the variable rank.
I looked at [intel website](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/mpi-library/developer-reference-linux/2021-11/hydra-environment-variables.html) but I couldn't find any variable that stores the rank value.
I need to get the rank value to be able to assign the correct files for each rank for compression.

Comment: This is _much_ more an MPI question than a bash question -- if you knew how to retrieve this data from a programing being invoked by mpi _in any language_, that would make it answerable in bash (f/e, if in Python it was `os.getenv("MPI_FOOBAR")`, then it would be `"$MPI_FOOBAR"` in shell); whereas to anyone with only bash expertise and no mpi expertise it isn't answerable at all.

Comment: There is no portable way to achieve this, and solutions will be specific to a given MPI vendor/version. That being said, `mpirun script` is an overkill and you can simply `srun script` and the rank is in `$SLURM_PROCID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Charles Duffy and Mr.Gilles Gouaillardet

I appreciate your insightful comments, which have helped me learn more and expand my knowledge of the problem's solution.

I found a solution on this [website](https://gist.github.com/serihiro/33f8f775cd8ba524d7b20d08d170e69c?permalink_comment_id=4188269), which includes creating a Python script that gets and prints out the MPI rank being used, the output of the Python script is an input to the rank variable in the bash script.

This solution works fine with me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).